# Node html-pdf Auto configuration failed

Tags: node.js, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I have a simple project using html-pdf package, I'd like to make a simple pdf file with this code :

```
...
    pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
            if (err) reject(err) ;
            else  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, '../../../assets/docs/idv_docs/')+data.link+'.pdf'));
          });
...
```

but I get this error messsage :

```
Error: html-pdf: Received the exit code '1'

    cc-server_1  | Auto configuration failed
    cc-server_1  | 139666354437760:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libssl_conf.so): libssl_conf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    cc-server_1  | 139666354437760:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
    cc-server_1  | 139666354437760:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=ssl_conf, path=ssl_conf
    cc-server_1  | 139666354437760:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=ssl_conf
    cc-server_1  |
    cc-server_1  |     at ChildProcess.respond (/usr/src/app/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:121:31)
    cc-server_1  |     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
    cc-server_1  |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
```

Comment: If using inside docker container you should use ENV OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null

Answer (score 46):

#### Solution without devOps

- fixed SSL issue: simulate empty config https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/issues/351#issuecomment-1116945290
- html-pdf assept options for `childprocess` wich will be paseed into phantomJs
- node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:89 (childProcessOptions)
- https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html
- added env object to childProcessOptions for overriding OPENSSL_CONF

```
pdf.create(html, {
  childProcessOptions: {
    env: {
      OPENSSL_CONF: '/dev/null',
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: The same error message while working with 'R' and 'webshot' could be solved here with accordingly setting the environment variable via `Sys.setenv(OPENSSL_CONF= '/dev/null')` before using 'webshot'

Comment: I was facing the same issues in Ubuntu 22 ,
 childProcessOptions: {
    env: {
      OPENSSL_CONF: '/dev/null',
    },
  }
this solution works for me.

Comment: Faced same issue. It  has worked for me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem, The problem is openssl.cnf file.
My operating system is Debian 10.
Try the following steps
Step 1:
Go to /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

Step 2:
Find the following line and comment it.

```
# System default
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

Step 3:
Restart your node server

Answer (score 0):

I use create it working for me

```
//pdf.js

const pdf = require('html-pdf');

function toPDF (html, options,  output) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pdf.create(html, options).toFile(output, function(error, response) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            else {
                resolve(response);
            }
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    toPDF: toPDF
}
```

When use

```
const options = { format: 'A4', base: './assets' }
const fileName = `PDFDemo-${Date.now()}`
const output = `./pdf/${fileName}.pdf`
let pdfResult = await pdfUtil.toPDF(html, options, output)
```