# html-pdf library did not create pdf on heroku server

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-to-pdf, html-pdf

This code collects data from Airtable, and creates pdf file to download.
It works perfectly on my localhost.
But when I deploy it to Heroku server, it throws an error:

> 2022-10-01T10:15:17.936106+00:00 app[web.1]: error create pdf Error: html-pdf: Unknown Error
>
> 2022-10-01T10:15:17.936125+00:00 app[web.1]: Auto configuration failed

```
let pdf = require("html-pdf");

//..... some code .... ...///

 ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, "../views/111.ejs"), {report1data : airtableData}, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                     console.log("error line 210"+err);
                } else {
                    let options = {
                            "format": 'A4',
                                "base":  'file:///' + __dirname,
                            };
                
                pdf.create(data, options).toFile(filename, function (err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                   console.log("error create pdf " + err);
                                } else {
                                    console.log("File created successfully");
                                    res.download('././'+filename);
                                }
                            });  //end pdf create
                        }
                    });  //end ejs render file*/

    });
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966814/node-html-pdf-auto-configuration-failed